# How to generate name of ID in base object in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have base object for all my entity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "entity_id")
    private Long id;

    /**
     *
     * @return true if the entity hasn't been persisted yet
     */
    @Transient
    public boolean isNew() {
        return id == null;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I need unicate name for id.

Like this:

```
user_id, car_id, cat_id
```

I dont know, how to do it, can you help me?

Its possible override anotation `Column(name = "entity_id")` in child class?

```
public class User extends BaseObject
public class Car extends BaseObject
public class Cat extends BaseObject
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes... you need to use [@AttributeOverride](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html) annotation on each subclass. For example,

```
@Entity
@AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="user_id"))
public class User extends BaseObject { ... }
```